# MvvmCross and Android Lifecycle order when restoring MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity

Tags: android-activity, save, mvvmcross, android-lifecycle, restore

I am testing the restore of every view in my app. I am doing this by allowing the orientation to be changed which destroys my MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity and then re-creates it.

When the activity is destroyed my fragment is also destroyed. At this point I tidy up my view model to ensure it will be free'd up and will not cause a memory leak.

However I have hit a problem where when OnCreate is called. It seems to do two things

1. Get a view model from the MvxFragmentExtensions OnCreate method by
   calling into the view model cache
2. Then calls RestoreViewModelsFromBundle

The problem is that the call to MvxFragmentExtensions OnCreate (1) calls into the view model cache and returns a view model which has not been Started e.g Start() called on it, but this is used to set the DataContext.

After RestoreViewModelsFromBundle (2) is called the DataContext is not set again event though it has gone through the Constructor->Init->RestoreState->Start set up. So I now have a view model which is not setup properly and so my view does not work.

When I took out my code to tidy the view models, I got a bit further as the cached view model set by (1) now had the correct data. But I am hitting other problems because it is attempting to create a new view model due to the call to RestoreViewModelsFromBundle (2).

It seems I have two instances of the view it is trying to restore, and one of them does not have a view model bound to it

What I really want is for the restored view model done in (2) to be bound to my view. Is there anyway to do this

Can someone from the MvvmCross team please help out with some information as to what is happening here and why? I have been looking into how the MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity is supposed to work for nearly 2 weeks. This is a major issue for me. I really need help from the person on the team who wrote or is familiar with the MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity class

Comment: It's a bit hard to figure out what's going on with your app here. Could you join us on Slack so we can communicate faster? Join at: https://xamarinchat.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I've signed up and posted a question to the #mvvmcross thread